# What is the path for policies in HashiCorp Vault?

Tags: path, policy, vault, hashicorp

I would like to create a policy which enable an appRole to edit polices.

```
path "????/????/*" {  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "patch", "delete", "list"]}
```

I couldn't found the path for policies.
Do you know any documents with all the paths?

Comment: Editing policies is independent of Vault. Reading from and writing policies to Vault depends on the specific target path.

Comment: @MattSchuchard it seems I found it:  https://<hostname>/v1/sys/policy

Comment: @MattSchuchard So, do you know how can I create/edit/delete policies (or any other under sys) from a nodeJS app using eg.: an approle? I don't want to use a root token in the frontend app. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
path "sys/policy" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}

path "sys/policy/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}

path "sys/policies/acl/*" {
  "capabilities" = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```